# Ember invoking closure action

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

In Ember JS, say I have a component defined as below (HBS/JS)

`parent.hbs`

```html
{{longclaw-sword attack=(action swing)}}
```

`app/components/longclaw-sword.js`

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  click() {
    this.attack();
  }
});
```

Is there any difference between calling the closure action using
`this.attack()` V/s `this.attr.attack()`?

In which cases is "attr" used ? Can it be used for reference to normal properties OR is it only for actions ?

Answer (score 5):

attr is kinda unofficially deprecated afaik.

in the upcoming edition of Ember, Octane, attributes will mean specifically HTML-only attributes, and *args* will be what is in ember-land.

In the future / Now (if you want to play with the octane blueprint (https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-octane-blueprint), the above would be this:

```
@action swing() {
  // whatever this does :)
}

<LongclawSword @attack={{this.swing}} />

// in longclaw-sword:
import Component from '@glimmer/component';

export default LongclawSword extends Component {
  @action click() {
    this.args.attack();
  }
}
// or, if you don't need to wrap attack, you can do this inside longclow's template:
<button {{on 'click' this.args.attack}}>click</button>
```